# How to document Web service for client

Tags: documentation, service

I am developing a web service. The business system of client will integrate with our system using these web service. I want to provide the documentation of our web service. What is the best practice for documenting the web service?

Answer (score 2):

IMO it should be close to the source with WSDL's wsdl:documentation element and XSD's xs:documentation element.  Although, while this is a valuable and maintainable solution for developers, it doesn't do well to expose the service capabilities to the business in a service-oriented environment.

Problem is, for Java developers anyway, that these elements are not supported by Java->WSDL with JAX-WS.